# Creating archive in Xcode doesn't work due to inter-file dependencies

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have an Xcode project that contains a custom rule to process .re files (re2c), and a set of input files in the project. These input files have dependencies on each other, for example, file2.re needs file1.re to be processed first.

My problem is as follows:

Despite setting the order correctly in the "Compile Sources" section in "Build Phases" tab of the project, the .re files get compiled in arbitrary order. This can be worked around, I can perform a build multiple times before all generated files are, well, generated.

But when I try to archive the project, Xcode always does a clean rebuild, so the generated files get deleted every time, and due to dependency issues, I cannot get a successful build at all.

My question is:
In a single target, is there a way to specify dependency between files built using custom rules, or a way to specify order of build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. The problem is due to custom rules executing in parallel, hence the apparent "random" order of execution. By setting the number of concurrent builds to 1, the problem does not occur, but of course, builds are much slower. Ce la vie.

Command for setting concurrent builds to 1:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks 1
```